# MySQL development tool with reverse & forward engineering capabilities

Tags: mysql, open-source, reverse-engineering, forward

I am looking for a development tool for working with MySQL Database. The must have features include reverse & forward engineering capabilities. One that I've liked is "ModelRight for MySQL" but it is weirdly overpriced. So I am looking for something free/open source or at least reasonably priced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across "MySQL Workbench". Check: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/  It comes with GPL & Commercial licenses. The tool suffices my needs as of now. The commercial license is for $99 which is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

**[NaviCat for MySQL](http://www.navicat.com/)** is an awesome tool for managing MySQL.  It's the best I've ever seen.  ~ $300 per seat, but if you are in business, well, well worth it.  They have a 30 day trial.

It has database diff and sync, so that may cover your forward and reverse engineering...